# Bootstrap popovers for SVG elements not working with jQuery 3.0.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, svg

I've been updating my dashboard application which uses Bootstrap and D3.js to the most recent versions of all its dependencies.

In the jump from 1.10.2 to 3.0.0 it looks like jQuery no longer returns context for $(this). It's been removed since .live() has been deprecated for a while now.

I wan't using .live(), but the fact that context is no longer returned breaks the positioning of my Bootstrap popovers for SVG elements generated by D3.js.

My code looks like this...

I have a function that is called on the mouseover of the SVG element:

```
function showPopover(d)
    {
        $(this).popover(
        {
            placement: 'auto left',
            container: 'body',
            trigger: 'manual',
            html : true,
            content: tip(d),              
        });
        $(this).popover('show');
    }
```

And here's how I call it:

```
svg.selectAll(".svg.rect")
            .on('mouseover', 
                    function(d)
                    { 
                        showPopover.call(this, d);
                    })        
            .on('mouseout',
                    function(d)
                    { 
                        $(this).popover('destroy');
                    });
```

With jQuery 1.10.2, this worked fine. Bootstrap's popover() function correctly generated the DIV's style based on the SVG element's position because $(this) returned the context.

But, with jQuery 3.0.0 context has been removed, so the popover() generates it's top and left coordinates based on the specified container (which is `<body>`). This causes the popover to appear in the top left of the page regardless of what element I'm mousing over.

Is there a different way to handle this in jQuery 3.0.0, or do I have to stick with the outdated version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 requires a jQuery version between 1.9.1 and 2.x (see their bower.json file here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/bower.json)
I have tried too to use jQuery 3 with Bootstrap 3 without success. It seems we will have to wait for Bootstrap 4 to be released.

Comment: Completely missed that. Thanks, Yves!